# Cross join returning row from only one table

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, cross-join

I'm trying to get two different columns by cross joining on same table but getting only on e column. Following is the sample query  :

select 1 from dual cross join (select 2 from dual) t1;

Expected Result : 1 2

but getting only 1.

Comment: Please provide actual details

Comment: You're selecting `1`. Perhaps, you want to select all columns (`select *`).

Comment: I was selecting columns in an incorrect manner. Selecting all required columns in 1st select statement solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

You have the `select` clause of

```
select 1
```

where you `select` a single column. If you want an output of 1 2 then use

```
select 1, 2
```

as your `select` clause.

Comment: Thanks, yes all required columns should be a part of first select statement

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast since your problem has been solved, please, mark the best answer as the correct answer, so later visitors will see the solution at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving data from `t1`

```
select 1 as id, t1.*
from dual cross join (select 2 id1 from dual) t1;
```